# Any differences between the editions of Human Occupied Landfill (HōL)?

Tags: edition-comparison, human-occupied-landfill

I've just been reminded that there are two editions of *Human Occupied Landfill (HōL)* – the first one published in 1994, the second one in 2002. I own the first edition core rulebook, as well as its sole (?) supplement, *Buttery Wholesomeness*.

**Are there any significant differences between the two editions of HōL?**

Also, am I right about the number and publication dates of the editions? (I did google them, but I'm not entirely sure about the reliability of the sources I've found.)

Answer (score 1):

HoL: Human Occupied Landfill

Author: Daniel Thron, Todd Shaugnessy, Chris Elliott

The key differences between editions would be the covers and the specific quality of the printing/paper. The Cabil edition proclaims to contain 4 new pages of material.

I base this information on owning the Black Dog edition and checking physical images of the other two editions, along with information from the current publishers site.

[image: HOL The Cabil edition]

- ISBN-10: 0966476514
- ISBN-13: 9780966476514
- Format: Trade Paper, Book
- Publisher: The Cabil Creative Services
- Publication Year: 2002
- Language: English

[image: HOL Black Dog Game Factory edition]

- ISBN-10: 1565045904
- ISBN-13: 9781565045903
- Format: Trade Paper, Book
- Publisher: Black Dog Game Factory (White Wolf Publishing)
- Publication Year: 1st printing, 1995; 2nd printing, 1999
- Language: English

[image: HOL Dirt Merchant edition]

- ISBN-10: ???
- ISBN-13: ???
- Format: Trade Paper, Book
- Publisher: Dirt Merchant Games
- Publication Year: 1994
- Language: English

Comment: So there's not much difference in game content beyond those four pages?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Are those 4 pages of bonus content noted in some way in the text (or is it a joke, like including 4 blank pages of Make Your Own Content)?

Comment: This is about as expected. It would be hard to do a "reprint" with changed content when the original is handwritten/drawn.